# Issue with RenderPartial in Telerik Modal Window using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

I'm having a brain meltdown since I'm combining Telerik extension with my own jQuery mix-up in my MVC3 project.

I want to be able to call ActionResult with Ajax like this:

```
    function showDialog(arg) {
    var url = '/Home/ReserveRent/';
    alert(arg);
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            data: { id: arg },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) { $('#RenderRent').html(data); },
            error: function(data) { alert(url+'  '+arg+'   '+data); }
        });
    var rentPayment = $('#RenderRent').html();
    $('#ModalPay' + arg).html(rentPayment);
    $('#Window' + arg).data('tWindow').center().open();
}
```

On page load I create multiple Telerik Windows which are hidden, I want to call upon each one of them with my jQuery above. My Razor page has these two Div tags included:

```
    <div>
@foreach (ShowAvailability availability in Model.ShowAvailabilities)
{
    foreach (var salesLine in availability.SalesLinesForSale)
    {
        SalesLine line = salesLine;
        Html.Telerik().Window()
        .Name("Window"+line.SalesLineID)
        .Title("Submit feedback")
        .Content(@<text>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("PayRent", "Payment", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "feedback-form" }))
            {
                <p class="note">This is <strong>salesLine</strong> @line.SalesLineID.</p>

                <div id='"ModalPay"+@line.SalesLineID'>
                    <!--TODO: Here will rendered Html be copied between Divs-->
                </div>
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <button type="submit" class="t-button t-state-default">Submit feedback!</button>
                </div>
            }
            </text>)
        .Buttons(b => b.Close())
        .Width(400)
        .Draggable(true)
        .Modal(true)
        .Visible(false)
        .Render();
    }
}
</div>
<div id="RenderRent" style="display: none;">
    <!-- TODO: Render payment info-->
    @{Html.RenderPartial("ReserveRent");}
</div>
```

As you can see within my Ajax request I will render the result within the Div tag marked as #RenderRent. I therefore want to replace that Div tag with the special Div tag within the Telerik Window, and the Window now should have the correct model-info within. My controller action is like this:

```
        public ActionResult ReserveRent(int salesLineId)
    {
        var salesLine = _salesLineLogic.GetSalesLine(salesLineId);

        if (!salesLine.IsAvailable)
        {
            ViewBag.AvailableSalesLine = @"Þessi orlosfeign er því miður ekki lengur til leigu á þessu tímabili.";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        salesLine.IsAvailable = false;
        _salesLineLogic.SaveToDatabase();

        var payment = new Payment { FK_SalesLineID = salesLineId, EditedBy = "PayRent.cshtml (GET)", EditedOn = DateTime.Now };

        return PartialView(new HomeFormViewModel(payment));
    }
```

For some reason the argument is not being received from the Ajax request, the salesLineId is always NULL. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong with the AjaxRequest, or if the jQuery function is not declared right?

Comment: Hi again.  I did see the errors of my ways with the Ajax request, the name of the argument I was passing into to controller action had wrong name, it should of course have been "saleslineId".

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't notice your comment. Is the problem now solved?

Comment: Thank you Tx3, well yes the problem is partially solved.  Now I get the correct data into my "#RenderRent" Div tag, but I have another problem concerning Telerik component.  

I want the Div tag to be copied over to the Telerik Dialog Window but it always pops up empty.  To rephrase, I want the #RenderRent Div tag to replace the #'"ModalPay"+@line.SalesLineID' tag insed the Telerik component.  Perhaps you can help me, is it ok to declare the div id this way?

Comment: It's really hard to say without knowing more about the app. If you have multiple containers then at least for me it looks reasonable to have "container" + index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ajax` call has incorrect data. Property inside your object literal (`id`) doesn't match to the `salesLineId` in the controller action.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: { salesLineId: arg },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) { $('#RenderRent').html(data); },
    error: function(data) { alert(url+'  '+arg+'   '+data); }
});
```

**Update**

There is also something weird on this line

```
<div id='"ModalPay"+@line.SalesLineID'>
```

It should be something like

```
<div id='ModalPay@(line.SalesLineID)' >
```

Comment: Thanx Tx3, I commented on your other comment  :)